# body: => Html in the Play framework?

Tags: scala, playframework

I just started to use the Play framework and Scala. What does body: => Html mean in the Play framework? Thanks.

Comment: Use http://symbolhound.com/ to find strange chars

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's call-by-name parameter

http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/FunctionalProgramming.html#_call_by_name_call_by_value

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who might stumble upon the same question:

It is called a **by-name parameter** and it is only evaluated if it is used in the function body.

This [link](https://alvinalexander.com/source-code/scala/simple-scala-call-name-example) explains the use of this notation in detail.

Also refer: [Scala Documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html)